# Were there ways to deal with distortion in the darkroom ages?

Tags: film, distortion, history, ultra-wide, enlarging

When people used early ultrawide angle lenses that had visible distortion, did they simply accept the fact and print it too ... or were there mitigations for things like critical architecture photography? Were contraptions like non-planar paper/film holders, and/or specialized optics in the enlarger light path, used?

Comment: Perspective distortions are corrected with tilts a-la-view-camera style. I'm not sure on pincushion/barrel distortion though...